# getRuntime().exec() return exit code 11

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am using  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` method to run a command and I get exit code 11 when I call `Process.waitFor()`.
When I run the same command on the console it runs as expected.

the command is:
hive  -hiveconf mapred.map.child.java.opts=-Xmx2048M -hiveconf mapred.job.shuffle.input.buffer.percent=0.30 -hiveconf io.sort.factor=25 -hiveconf io.sort.mb=256 -hiveconf mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks=500 -hiveconf mapred.job.priority=VERY_LOW -e select site_id,count(session_id) from my_table where day = '20111017' group by site_id;

I am running on Unix machine.

Any idea why? What is exit code 11?

Comment: That depends on the program you're starting. If you run it on the command line, type `echo $?` _right after_ it finishes (no other commands in between).

Comment: I get `command not found: a command`. Seriously, you need to tell us *which* command you are running. Exit codes depend on the program you (try to) invoke!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it I changed the command to be:

hive -hiveconf mapred.map.child.java.opts=-Xmx2048M -hiveconf mapred.job.shuffle.input.buffer.percent=0.30 -hiveconf io.sort.factor=25 -hiveconf io.sort.mb=256 -hiveconf mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks=500 -hiveconf mapred.job.priority=VERY_LOW -f filename;

As you can see I changed the -e query to -f filename.

Answer (score 1):

The exit code is set by the program you call. There is no unique definition, except that `0` is usually no error, and anything else indicates an error. Error codes vary completely from program to program, and some programs do not bother to set an error code.

```
System.exit(n);
```

is the Java way to set the exit code to `n` (an integer value). So, when do ''you'' use `System.exit(11);`? Then you have your answer...

Answer (score 1):

`Process.waitFor()` blocks the thread until exit code from the forked child process is received. In your case this exit code `11` depends on the external command. Please, check the man pages of the external command.